# "Format > Protection" is greyed out in Visio 2003

Tags: microsoft-visio

I use Visio 2003 (With CaseMap) and when I try to modify my documents, I get the following error message:

Shape protection and/or layer properties prevent complete execution of this command [(MS Link)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924113)

But the weirdest thing is that I need to modify the protection properties but I can't. The Protection option is greyed out in Format menu. Is there anything that can be done so I can manage these protections?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

There may be good reasons why the shape is protected in this way, so you should keep that in mind, but to answer your question:

I replicated this issue in Visio 2007 by locking the Layer.

As you can see I have disabled by **Protection** menu via the layer:

[image]

It sounds like you are having the same issue.

Here are some instructions for removing the layer locking in Visio 2007. The steps should be similar in Visio 2003

Go to **File > View** and select **Layer Properties**

[image]

In the screenshot below you'll see that one of the layers (called "mylayer") is locked and one is not. (The shape I drew is in "mylayer") To remove the locking for "mylayer" unclick that Lock checkbox.

[image]

Now you can see that the the shape can be modified:

[image]